# create-react-app Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug: Error: spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a react application, but it gives the following errors:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite\mysite\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template-typescript...


Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
   at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
   at Object.spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
   at spawn (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js:12:24)
   at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:390:19
   at new Promise (<anonymous>)
   at install (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:341:10)
   at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:468:16
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
 errno: -4094,
 code: 'UNKNOWN',
 syscall: 'spawn'
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite\mysite
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error. It was because my anti-virus software viewed the react installation as malware.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache  `npm cache clean --force` than `npx clear-npx-cache` and run again `npx create-react-app my-app` or `npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm`.

If You still have this problem run Try to run `cmd` as administrator.
If You installed `create-react-app` *globaly* than run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`.
Also notice that `create-react-app` required **Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine**

Comment: did everything. did not help

Comment: I had this issue couple times restart machine and check it out. Try to run your command as admin. Good Luck and best regards! ;-) what  are you using powershell or cmd?

Comment: If you installed create-react-app globally, Uninstall this and then clean the cache, finally run npx create-react-app my-app ! I hope it should work for You! ;-)

Comment: I rebooted the machine but the problem persists. i use powshell

Comment: Try to use CMD as admin ! Clean the cache and run npx ....

Comment: cleared the cache. problem still exists

Comment: Did you run `npx clear-npx-cache` also  before run `npx create-react-app` ?

Comment: yes, i did it .

Comment: What are your node and npm version ? Try to update them or Lastly you could use **yarn** instead of npm ...

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite>node -v
v16.13.1

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite>npm -v
8.3.0

Comment: Run `npm cache verify` and show the output please ;-)

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 140 (3388183 bytes)
Index entries: 140
Finished in 1s

Comment: Your cache is **not cleared** !  Run `npm cache clean --force` or `npm cache clean -f`  ! Then run `npm cache verify` You should have values = 0

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite>npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite>npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.011s

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\study\portfoliosite>

Comment: Okay ! Now `npx clear-npx-cache` and after this command `npx create-react-app my-app` and it's should work now !

Comment: nope :( didnt work. aahhhh

Comment: I have no ideas anymore, forgive me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For me It's a antivirus issue, update your antivirus and try. I have faced this issue in windows 11.

Scan your pc/laptop with updated antivirus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).